# Consuming Oracle ORDS RESTful api with C#

Tags: c#, oracle, rest, webservice-client, oracle-ords

I get the below response on consuming ORDS Oracle RESTful Data services using C#.

> {
>       StatusCode: 405, 
>       ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', 
>       Version: 1.1, 
>       Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, 
>       Headers:
>       {
>           Content-Length: 11402
>           Content-Type: text/html
>       } }

```
public void test()
{
    string item_code;

    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        Item items = new Item
        {
            segment1 = "049002932",
            description = "Fine Liner Dollar Pointer Softliner Metal Jacket F 0.3 Black 10's Box",
            short_description = " Pointer F Black 10's Box", service_item = "No", primary_uom_code = "10", inventory_item_status_code = "Inactive"
        };

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://10.132.1.40:8090/");

        var response = client.PutAsJsonAsync("ords/ebsvis1/raz_inv/raz_item/Update/", items).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            Console.Write("Success");
        else
            Console.Write("Error");
    }
}
```

Here is my RESTful Services definition:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For your ORDS based RESTful Service, do you have a PUT handler defined for your raz_inv module and your .../Update/ template?

Based on your screenshot, this is the PUT Hander URI:

```
/raz_inv/raz_item/update/{item_code}
```

But, you're doing a PUT on

```
/raz_inv/raz_item/Update/
```

You need to include the item code on the end of the URI, so do a

```
var response client.PutAsJsonAsync("ords/ebsvis1/raz_inv/raz_item/Update/049002932",  items).Result;
```

Just guessing on the 049002932 bits...

Comment: I have created a method with PUT in ORDS, thats why I am using PutAsJsonAsync

Comment: I have attached screenshot. You can see in link above.

Comment: {StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Length: 11402
  Content-Type: text/html
}}

Comment: can you exercise the api outside of your code, can you use something like Insomnia or Postman to do the PUT? Also, what is 'items' - are you appending that to the URI? Sorry, I don't speak C#

Comment: Item code is in Json format which updates the description of the item exists in database. However I will give a try outside my code as you suggested. Will keep you updated with the progress.